# How can I make a form "unresponsive"?

Tags: c#, forms

Currently I have 2 forms open. However, I want one of both to be unresponsive while the other one is open.

It's not easy to describe, but I think all of you know that "plinging" sound when clicking on a main window while a prompt window of that form is open.

Is there a way to do this relatively quick?

I am pretty sure it would work with

```
Window.Enabled = false;
```

but I would prefer a way to perform it by setting an attribute only on the window I want the user to work on in that moment, instead of having to disable all others.

I could imagine something like

```
dialogwindow.Focus = true;
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is the second form a child of the first? If so you want `secondForm.ShowDialog();`

Comment: The proper term for this is "modal dialog"

Comment: Oh, I see. Didn't know that. Thanks though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you show your second window - you should show it with this [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/c7ykbedk(v=VS.110).aspx):

```
dialogWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: You may also want to specify *owner* by using [overriden](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe(v=vs.110).aspx) version.